# How to declare resource before Window in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

My code:

```
<Window ...
    Title="Notification" Height="90" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" DataContext="{Binding Notification, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Opacity="{Binding TransitionOpacity}" Left="{Binding LeftMargin}" Top="{Binding TopMargin}"  Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#FF3C4759">
    ...
</Window>
```

While compiling I get exception *System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException* and after change code to

```
<Window ...
    Title="Notification" Height="90" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" DataContext="{Binding Notification, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Opacity="{Binding TransitionOpacity}"  Left="{Binding LeftMargin}" Top="{Binding TopMargin}" >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#FF3C4759" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
    ...
</Window>
```

it works but I want to set Window visibility instead of Grid.

Comment: you cannot add data bindings to static resources. either use triggers in your resource to change the styling, or do not declare your grid as a resource, but just as a normal element and use your bindings.

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to set Window Visibility"? do you want to show and hide the window depending on `IsVisible`?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow yes

Comment: @XAMlMAX How in this case?

Comment: @XAMlMAX no, this won't help. Archer: instead of "not showing" the window, is setting the `WindowState` to `WindowState.Minimized` a solution? You could definitely bind to that using a custom converter as well. If it is, then I will do a working example for you.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, hence removed comment. Your Visibility is the issue here. Is the manipulation of the window visibility really the way to go? Why do you need to hide the window?

Comment: It should become invisible after few seconds because it is notification

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow That's not what I want but please show me example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding window visibility might be not a good idea in this case. If you have a notification which you want to hide after some time - just close it (`Close()`) instead of hiding.

If however you still want to do this - put converter into your application ( `App.xaml` file). Then you will be able to use it in `Window.Visibility` binding. As of now - window `Visibility` property is set *before* `Window.Resources` are initialized, so you cannot use converter created inside `Window.Resources`.

Alternative way is to set `Visibility` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="IsVisible" Converter="{StaticResource BoolToVisibility}" />
</Window.Visibility>
```

Comment: Thank you but I want do not close Notification because I would like to use the same window multiple times (when get messenger message). How to put converter into *App.xaml*?

Comment: @ArcheR `<Application x:Class="..."             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="..."
             StartupUri="Notification.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>`

Comment: Still does not working (now it is all the time hidden)

Comment: @ArcheR does your ViewModel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Do you set different values to `IsVisible`?

Comment: @ArcheR Many things can go wrong. Your converter may be wrong (reversed), model might not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, anything else for which you didn't provide a code. But converter will work this way (note - no xaml parse exception any more).

Comment: Try to set your view model as window `DataContext` _before_ calling window `InitializeComponent()` also.